# Почему после добавления кода в application.css и перезапуска сервера весь добавленный код пропадает?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarn

В *application.css* весь код стилей **bootstrap**. Вот начало:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Bootstrap  v5.3.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2023 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */
:root,
[data-bs-theme=light] {
  --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
  --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
```

Сервер я запускаю с помощью `foreman start`. Вот логи:

```
20:28:48 web.1  | started with pid 52258
20:28:48 js.1   | started with pid 52259
20:28:48 css.1  | started with pid 52261
20:28:49 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.19
20:28:49 css.1  | $ nodemon --watch ./app/assets/stylesheets/ --ext scss --exec "yarn build:css"
20:28:49 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
20:28:49 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets --watch
20:28:49 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
20:28:49 css.1  | [nodemon] 3.0.1
20:28:49 css.1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
20:28:49 css.1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): app/assets/stylesheets/**/*
20:28:49 css.1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: scss
20:28:49 css.1  | [nodemon] starting `yarn build:css`
20:28:49 css.1  | $ yarn build:css:compile && yarn build:css:prefix
20:28:49 css.1  | $ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules 
20:28:49 web.1  | DEBUGGER: Debugger can attach via UNIX domain socket (/run/user/1000/ruby-debug-loza-52260)
20:28:50 web.1  | => Booting Puma
20:28:50 web.1  | => Rails 7.0.6 application starting in development 
20:28:50 web.1  | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
20:28:51 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
20:28:51 web.1  | * Puma version: 5.6.6 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Birdie's Version")
20:28:51 web.1  | *  Min threads: 5
20:28:51 web.1  | *  Max threads: 5
20:28:51 web.1  | *  Environment: development
20:28:51 web.1  | *          PID: 52260
20:28:51 web.1  | * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
20:28:51 web.1  | * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
20:28:51 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
20:28:51 css.1  | $ postcss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --use=autoprefixer --output=./app/assets/builds/application.css
20:28:53 css.1  | [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Я пишу какие-то стили перед `root:`. Они работают, но после перезапуска сервера весь добавленный код исчезает. Такое впечатление, что какой-то процесс за этим следит и не дает добавлять код. В чем причина и как побороть это?

Comment: Очевидно, причина в этом: `$ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css`

Comment: Подскажите как это можно исправить, что то я сам никак не дойду или ткните носом в документацию

Comment: Вы код кладёте в builds/application.css? Этот файл генерится автоматически, когда компилятся ассеты, что-то класть туда бесполезно. Бутстрап подключается гемом и импортится в app/assets/stylesheets - посмотрите внимательно доку по гему. Я сама давно им не пользовалась, точно не подскажу сейчас

Comment: Спасибо стили заработали